# Cartesian equation of three points

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the Cartesian equation through the point (-6,4) and perpendicular to the segment formed by the points (3,7) and (-4,-2).

Would they first step be to find the cross product?

Comment: $A(a_1,a_2),B(b_1,b_2),C(c_1,c_2)$

Line Passing by $A$: $y=(x-a_1)m+a_2$

Line $BC$: $\dfrac{y-b_2}{x-b_1}=\dfrac{c_2-b_2}{c_1-b_1}$

The pente you need is $m=-\left(\dfrac{c_1-b_1}{c_2-b_2}\right)$

Comment: What’s the cross product of 2-D vectors?

Answer (score 0):

The line containing points $(3,7)$ and $(-4,-2)$ has a slope $m=\dfrac{-2-7}{-4-3}=\dfrac{9}{7}$

The perpendicular line has a slope $m^{\perp}=-\dfrac{1}{m}=-\dfrac{7}{9}$

The line passing through $(-6,4)$ and having slope $m^{\perp}$ has equation

$y-4=-\dfrac{7}{9}(x+6)$

$y=-\dfrac{7 x}{9}-\dfrac{2}{3}$

Hope this helps